# Extracting values from an array mathematica

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I have this MATLAB code for creating a linearly spaced vector with `Nt+1` columns. `tx(i)` is used to extract the `timee` values from `ti`.

```
Nt = 20;
t0 = 0; tf = 1;
ti = linspace(t0, tf, Nt+1);
timee = [0.1 0.3 0.5 0.7 0.9 1];
tx = zeros(length(timee),1);
for i  = 1:length(timee)
tx(i) = find(ti == timee(i));
end
```

To re-create the linearly spaced vector in Mathematica, I used the code

```
Mt = 10;
t0 = 0; tf = 1;
ti = Array[# &, Mt, {t0, tf}] 
timee = {1/10, 3/10, 1/2, 7/10, 9/10,1};
```

I want to extract the `timee` values the same way I did using MATLAB. Can anyone assist with ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Nothing to do with the answer, but you can avoid the loop in matlab with `tx = find(ismember(ti,timee))`. Or `[~,tx] = intersect(ti,timee)`

Comment: look up `Select` , `Cases` , `Position` and `Range` and `Subdivide` as well.

Comment: Alright, I will try them out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mayor,
please check this code

```
Mt = 11;
t0 = 0; tf = 1;
ti = Range[t0, tf, (tf - t0)/(Mt - 1)]
timee = {1/10, 3/10, 1/2, 7/10, 9/10, 1}
tx = Table[If[Length[Position[timee, ti[[i]]]] > 0, i, 0], {i, 1, Mt}]
```

Maybe I didn't understand your problem properly. If so, tell me more details.

Comment: This works perfectly. I just made little adjustments. If you do not mind though, is there a way I could just extract the values I need? I want to avoid having "zero" or "null" entries in `tx`.                                   
                                                                                                                 
    `Mt = 10;
    t0 = 0; tf = 1;
    ti = Range[t0, tf, (tf - t0)/(Mt)]
    timee = {1/10, 3/10, 1/2, 7/10, 9/10, 1};
    tx = Table[If[Length[Position[timee, ti[[i]]]] > 0, i], {i, 1, Mt + 1}] `

Comment: And what would you like to have there instead? Can you give an example in numbers.

For exmaple, if you want to delete these "zero: elements then just
tx=DeleteCases[tx, 0]